# Panasonic lens adapter

Tags: lens, adapter

Is there an adapter for my Panasonic GH4 that will allow me to use a Kiron      28-210mm telephoto lens ? My father used this lens on his Canon AV-1 which I believe is a C/FD mount.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude and say "let me google that for you", but, well, I just googled ["fd mount to micro four thirds"](https://www.google.com/search?q=fd+mount+to+micro+four+thirds) and came up with a list of adapters from Vello, Photodiox, Fotasy, Metabones, etc.

Comment: I still own a Kiron 28-210 that I bought in about 1986 for a Konica FS-1. Compared to more recent lenses with even very modest prices, the Kiron probably isn't worth the trouble and the price of an adapter.